How to format a number with 6 decimal places using `$A.localizationService` in an Aura Component?
I am working on an Aura component where I need to format a number based on the user's locale, specifically for Greek formatting. For example, when the user has a Greek locale, the entered number 123.451231 should be displayed as 123,451231 (with a comma as a decimal separator and 6 decimal places).
I have tried using $A.localizationService.formatNumber(), but they round the number to 3 decimal places, as shown below.
Code snippet tried in browser console:
var num = 123.451231;
$A.localizationService.formatNumber(num);

Output:
'123,451'

What I am expecting is:
'123,451231'

How can I achieve this formatting while preserving all 6 decimal places? Any other approach to achieve this in Aura component?

I don't see an option to specify this using the $A framework.
You can try using the JS "Intl.NumberFormat" object:
new Intl.NumberFormat('el-GR', { maximumSignificantDigits: 9}).format('123.451231')

